# I tried to change the permalink structure of URL's in WordPress but it did not work. The .htaccess file is overwritten but this is hosted on cloud

Tags: .htaccess, url, cloud, permalinks

I have changed the permalink structure to have "%post name%" structure from "Page_id" structure. It didnot update the URLs properly and says page cannot be found on the server. I tried to overwrite the .htaccess file content via WP File Manager but still did not work. This site is hosted in Google Cloud and I have no idea what should I do as I think it has something to do with hosting issue.

Please let me know how do I troubleshoot...Thanks in advance :)

overwriting the .htaccess file.

Comment: You have to add more details to your question, since we cannot somehow magically guess your setup. 1. Which are the rules that you or WP implemented, 2. What _exactly_ happens when you request one of the new rules (what does the http server's error log file say and what does your browsers network console say), where did you put that ".htaccess" file and how did you enable the http server to consider that file?